# UPDATE Stock table quantity based on Order

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble creating a sql statement that will update the Inventory table based on the Inbound orders table.

INBOUND

```
OrderID  ProductID  Description  ShipQty
001      2          Apple        3
002      4          Orange       4
003      1          Grape        1
004      2          Apple        6
005      5          Strawberry   3
006      3          Pear         1
007      1          Grape        2
```

INVENTORY

```
ProductID  Description  Qty
1          Grape        10
2          Apple        10
3          Pear         10
4          Orange       10
5          Strawberry   10
```

WHAT INVENTORY SHOULD LOOK LIKE AFTER THE UPDATE

```
ProductID  Description  Qty
1          Grape        13
2          Apple        19
3          Pear         11
4          Orange       14
5          Strawberry   13
```

Comment: describe the trouble you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE INVENTORY
SET Qty = Qty + (SELECT SUM(ShipQty) FROM INBOUND WHERE ProductID = INVENTORY.ProductID)
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly! Thank you. My version was only adding the first instance of each product in the Inbound table and ignoring the 2nd instance.

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
update INVENTORY
set qty = qty + TotalQty
from (
select INBOUND.ProductID, sum(shipqty) as TotalQty
from INBOUND
group by INBOUND.ProductID
) as a
where a.ProductID = INVENTORY.ProductID
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, it keeps giving me syntax errors that I cannot fix.  I have a working sqlfiddle here to test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c141c/1